# figure - figcaption - responsive website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Sorry, this looks easy but I can't seem to make it work.

I just want a website exactly like this:

[image: mywebsite]

I want it to be responsive, to work/look good on tablets and smartphones too.

I've tried everything but nothing seems to work.

So far I came up with this:

```html
<div id="container">  
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div id="grid">
    <figure id="r">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
        <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure> 

    <figure id="p">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
        <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure id="c">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
        <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure id="s">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
        <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm inexperienced in html/css but need it for tomorrow. Maybe you can help me, or post an example, maybe a website that is similar to what I want. Thank you very much.

Comment: This example may help: https://codepen.io/bradfrost/full/GlrHv

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and `@media` *queries*:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {margin: 0}

#container {
  width: 1200px; /* adjust */
  max-width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
  margin: 0 auto; /* horizontally centered on the page */
  padding: 0 5px; /* adjust */
}

h1 {text-align: center}

#flex {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables their wrapping */
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  display: flex; /* flex behavior also for figure elements */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks flex-items vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them vertically */
  align-items: center; /* and horizontally */
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px); /* initial width set to 50% - 10px (2 x 5px left & right padding) of the flex-container's (#flex) width */
  margin: 5px; /* adjust */
}

img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  max-width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
}

@media (max-width: 568px) { /* adjust */
  #flex {flex-direction: column}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">  
  <h1>title</h1>
  <div id="flex">
    <figure id="r">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure> 

    <figure id="p">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure id="c">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure id="s">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      <figcaption>caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```